# How does Graphpad Prism do it’s „Normalization” when doing a dose-response curve?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, normalization

I would like to understand how Prism does its data normalization to Percentage „magic”. Here is the user guid to do it:

http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/7/user-guide/index.htm?using_normalizing_data.htm

I understand what it does with the average values.

But I’m interested in what it does with the SD and SEM values.

The user guide only telling this: „Each SD or SEM is normalized appropriately.”

Here is an example of my calculated AVG, SD and SEM by Concentration from my raw data:

```
     AVG         SD            SEM
5119,555556  546,4435266   182,1478422

19989,33333  3466,049048   1155,349683
25613,44444  4561,185869   1520,39529
27765,11111  5564,505334   1854,835111
27970,88889  6138,975453   2046,325151
30191,88889  4364,60472    1454,86824
29222,44444  5644,638343   1881,546114
29491,88889  4868,367397   1622,789132
29257,77778  4417,984291   1472,66143
31071,88889  4787,055605   1595,685202

31452,22222  3808,832786   1269,610929
```

Prism’s normalised data:

```
     AVG %        SD            SEM
0            2,075154535  0,691718178

56,46894014  13,1625448   4,387514934
77,82686482  17,32139751  5,77379917
85,99795775  21,13156789  7,043855963
86,77941214  23,31315522  7,771051739
95,21380288  16,57486792  5,524955973
91,53227508  21,43587816  7,145292721
92,55550773  18,48793918  6,162646392
91,66645569  16,77758028  5,592526761
98,55565964  18,1791524   6,059717467

100          14,46428816  4,821429386
```

As I mentioned, I know what happens with the first column:

```
((value-minOfValues)/(maxOfValues-minOfValues))*100
```

But can someone explain me what kind of calculation is done on the SD and SEM columns?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism is taking the SD and SEM of the normalized (%) values. You can verify that by noting that subtracting a constant from a data set does not affect the SD and that scaling a data set by a constant scales the SD by the same constant (i.e. $SD(aX-b) = a\cdot SD(X)$). Similarly, since $SEM(X) = \frac{SD(X)}{\sqrt{n-1}}$,

$$SEM(aX-b) = \frac{SD(aX-b)}{\sqrt{n-1}}=\frac{a\cdot SD(X)}{\sqrt{n-1}}=a \cdot SEM(X)$$

Therefore the SD of the normalized values should differ from the SD of the raw data by a factor of `100 / (maxOfValues - minOfValues)`. The SEM of the normalized values should differ from the SEM of the raw data by the same factor.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation, now it makes lot more sense!
Cheers!